# How to make VS2019 not create folder 'net5.0' for building project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I'm created a solution (with 1 project) in VS 2019 with TargetFramework .NET 5.0 (NET Core). I set OutputPath (in Properties of Project)  to 'bin\SomeMyFolder' and expected that all my output files will be there. But it turns out that inside folder '**SomeMyFolde**r' lays other folder '**net5.0**' and my files are inside it. I have never seen such custom folders, created by VS previously, with other .Net Framework version. Is there any way to disable VS 2019 from creating that folder and build my project in that folder, which I set (right into **SomeMyFolder**)?
P.S: Please, do not advise some scrips on post-build event like 'copy SomeMyFolder\net5.0 -> SomeMyFolder | rmdir SomeMyFolder'

Comment: This isn't a Visual Studio issue and can't change. .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5, not .NET Framework 5, and uses a completely different build system which allows targeting multiple runtimes and OSs.  In all .NET Core projects, building will create a version-specific folder

Comment: `I have never seen such custom folders` on the contrary, they appear in all NET Core projects. They aren't custom. `other .Net Framework version.` you aren't targeting .NET Framework any more

Comment: `Please, do not advise` why do you want to change the default path? Did you encounter an actual problem with eg a publishing or packaging script? You need to change that script then

Comment: Reiterating Panagiotis' comment, this is a [feature of .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build), **not** Visual Studio. Starting in .NET Core, all .NET projects output like this.

Comment: Not OP, but I've got old projects that cannot be changed without discussions up the chain of command, and newer projects that I use to build their files into the right place in a way where I can make one solution with all of the projects used by some subsystem.
In my case post-build scripts seem to run concurrent with later projects, and are persisted on the project file which I shouldn't be changing except to add new files. Using the build location of a empty class libraries that reference a set of projects works, but requires that those projects build where I say and not in a subfolder.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This can be disabled in your csproj file by adding a propertygroup like this.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#appendtargetframeworktooutputpath

Comment: Thank you for help!